# Charging a series of Nissan Leaf Li-Ion Batteries

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have an electric motorcycle I built out of a 1995 Suzuki GS500e.

Right now it has four Optima Yellow Top AGM batteries in series giving me around 48v of power.

I want more range out of the bike without sacrificing performance, so I have been looking into Nissan Leaf Li-Ion cells. They're cheap, small and stackable.

At 7.6v each, I'd need 8 of them to get me to where I am, and as I hone in on my desired range, I will just add batteries (my AXE controller allows scaling).

Through all of my research, I can't figure out the best way to charge them while connected in the array (safely). Presently, I have an on-board charger and I can plug in at Level 1 EV charging stations, i'd like the same for the Leaf batteries.

What would I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: A 48 V Li-ion charger with built-in balancing?

Comment: Of course, I am specifically asking about the Nissan Leaf cells, they are a little different.

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: Nissan provides a rail system for the batteries to be connected in series, on the end of the rail is a positive and negative wire for energy output, but the tops of the batteries remain covered by the rail. The rail themselves are simply quick connectors to link the batteries in series, but the batteries which contain two cells each must certainly be balanced and charged individually, correct?

Comment: Strange. Draw a schematic of what the actual problem is.

Comment: The problem is I cant get to the individual cells once they are connected using the provided rail; maybe I answered my own question and it's time to NIX the rail and access the cells from overhead. Let me think a bit and I'll be back with a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Li ion batteries are charged with balancing in mind.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVhC3W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic imagine that the voltage sources are batteries. In the first schematic a bunch on cells are in series. The cells are charged by some high current source. The cell voltages are monitored by balancing circuitry. The circuitry will bypass some charge around cells that are more charged than others. The circuitry reports to the high current source letting it know how the cells are doing and what mode to charge the cells in. The starting mode is constant current and when the cells reach a predetermined voltage the mode switches to constant current.

This setup scales when adding more cells in parallel.

You would need to buy a charger that connects to the batteries as described. That can talk to a charging station. That supports balancing lithium ion cells.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful diagram, although I am very aware of that. I am "afraid" of using the wrong BMS charger for the Leaf cells, the internet is a place where you can get an answer to support anything regardless of research or fact, so I want to be clear and concise and above all, safe. Do you by any chance have a recommendation for such a charger?

Comment: I used the Delta-Q QuiQ charger and an Orion BMS; and ditched the stock rails that the Leaf cells came with, I was confused early on because of ignorance, but later found they're exactly the same as every other lithium cell out there in regards to connectivity.

Comment: Glad i could be of help.